# Android youtube player app, google play rejected for background playing

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api, google-play

I have been working on android youtube player app like Viral Popup. And published successfully to Google Play. But after few days it rejected with :

> "After a regular review, we have determined that your app enables
>   background playing of YouTube videos, which is a violation of the
>   YouTube API Terms of Service: Your API Client will not, and You will
>   not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third
>   parties to: (8) separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video
>   components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through
>   the YouTube API;"

statements.

And I changed my app logic. For now it stops video playing after screen lock. (I think it is what Google want from me. Background playing related thing..) And uploaded again. But nothing changed with google reject. Still same "... we have determined that your app enables background playing..."

So guys if you have same issue, how do you solve this? What would I do now? How to NOT violate YouTube API TOS[8]?

Answer (score 2):

> For now it stops video playing after screen lock.

I don't think that this is enough.

> The terms of service require that you do not separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components.

I interpret this to mean that you must not play Youtube **audio without the video being visible**, and not play **video without the audio being audible**.

This means that you may not continue playback if your app goes into the background, ***even if the screen is on***. Please check to make sure that this does not happen, even by accident (for example, another app launches on top of your app).